# Пики в показаниях датчиков DHT11 esp8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Имеется сборка esp12s (esp8266) + dht11 + ccs811, которая передает данные по MQTT на сервер в базу influxDB и строит график по показаниям в Grafana.

На графиках (собственно и в базе на данных) присутствуют странные пики многократно превышающие базовые значения по обоим показателям датчика dht11, при этом с датчика ccs811 данные приходят нормально.

Данные снимаются стандартным методом:

```
int h = dht.readHumidity(); // считываем влажность
int t = dht.readTemperature(); // считываем температуру в градусах цельсия
```

Не могу понять как побороть эти всплески, кроме введения переменных и сравнения новых значений с датчиков с предыдущими и ручного отсекания пиков

[image: пример графиков по одному и тому же времени]

Comment: Без введения дополнительной переменной - просто считать заведомо большие значения невалидными и игнорировать. Или запрашивать повторно через несколько секунд.

Comment: Без хранения предыдущего (адекватного) значения на графике будет провал до нуля

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, устройство само говорит MQTT брокеру, что у него есть значение, вот оно. Просто в момент таких пиков ничего не передавать. Дальше уже сервер пусть сам сглаживает эти пропуски. Будет просто отсутствие данных на какой-то момент времени, а не подогнанные данные.

Comment: Спасибо, отлично получилось

Comment: DHT11 передают контрольную сумму в конце пакета. При опросе, если контрольная сумма не сошлась - следует перезапросить данные ещё раз.